# Total Days difference is not showing properly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get a total days between 2 dates

Query

```
Select DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2012', 103), CONVERT(DATETIME, '31/01/2012', 103))
```

The above query is showing 30 days, instead of 31

How to modify my query for 31 days

Comment: it looks right to me. 31-1=30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want 31, probably what you are looking for is

```
Select DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2012', 103), CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/02/2012', 103))
```

Between 01.01 and 31.01 there is only 30 whole days.